# Use actionlib across ROS releases?

Tags: ros-kinetic, actionlib, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use actionlib across ROS releases, specifically kinetic and indigo? When I attempt this, I get no error, but my action client hangs on waitForServer(). Everything works fine if everything is running on indigo.

In debug output, I do receive "Getting status over the wire.".

Upon further inspection, it appears to be a TCP port issue. The ports actionlib tries to use are not open on either machine. Is there a range of ports that actionlib attempts to use, so I know what to open? It looks like it varies widely, as I see it attempting ports in the 30000s on one machine and in the 50000-60000s on another.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270450/use-actionlib-across-ros-releases?/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actionlib is using topics under the hood, so all the problems with pub/sub from/to different ros releases apply here as well (ie: msg def changes will make things not work, etc) and the same holds for the multi-machine aspect here.

> Upon further inspection, it appears to be a TCP port issue. The ports actionlib tries to use are not open on either machine. Is there a range of ports that actionlib attempts to use, so I know what to open? It looks like it varies widely, as I see it attempting ports in the 30000s on one machine and in the 50000-60000s on another.

No, there is no 'range of ports' for actionlib, as it's not a stand-alone communication library, but uses ROS infrastructure for everything. Client libraries typically do not support limiting ports used (I would actually say they all assume a completely wide open network for all involved hosts), but they also do not request *specific* ports in most cases. On Linux, the regular TCP/IP stack is used and that will attempt to use any port from the *ephemeral range* for a standard installation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1